# Meaning of mathematical equation and symbols in the research paper algorithm

Tags: notation, algorithms, computer-science

I am trying to understand the algorithm provided in "Wang, H., He, C., & Li, Z. (2020). A new ensemble feature selection approach based on genetic algorithm. Soft Computing, 24(20), 15811-15820." I am finding it difficult to make sense of the algorithm in line number 9. Can anyone help me understand this please?

I understood so far for line number 9 that

a) Sum all values from 1 till T

I am finding it difficult to understand below points

a) $w_i$ ✕ $FS_i;$

- Does it mean multiplication of value of $w_i$ which is represented as {0,1} with $FS_i$? In other words, deciding whether base Learner $T$ will be included or not at this index.

Additionally what does $;$ mean?

b) $//W=[w_1,w_2,...w_t]^T$

This, I am unable to get it.

- What does $//$ mean here?
- Also, what does $W=[w_1,w_2,...w_t]^T$ mean? Some sort of transpose? Please suggest.

**----Complete algorithm below----**

[image]

Comment: In some programming languages "//" means that what follows is a comment, i.e. it is not executable code.

Comment: @JonathanZ supports MonicaC Thank you! Can you please help me understand rest of the content in line number 9?